# How to convert rawString to JSON Array?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to convert jsonString.rawString() to JSON object, but it returns nil.

```
let jsonData = newsfeedData.rawString()?.data(using: .utf8)
let object = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData!, options: .mutableContainers)
print(object) //it returns nil
```

This is the jsonString:

Printing description of newsfeedData.rawString:

```
"Data:[{\"UserID\":1,\"post\":[{\"PostId\":1,\"UserId\":1,\"UserName\":\"party Patel\",\"ImagePath\":\"/Files/User/user_20180606_040913967_Hydrangeas.jpg\",\"FileId\":2108,\"FileName\":\"Business Category.png\",\"Email\":\"parth.patel@shaligraminfotech.com\",\"Location\":\"Ahmedabad\",\"PostDescription\":\"P7800\",\"PostPath\":\"/Files/NewsFeed/Photo/fd1c7fcf-e1d0-4ffe-afb4-42bb3fea4fa4.PNG\",\"UserRole\":\"Business\",\"BusinessName\":\"Shaligram infotech\",\"PostType\":false,\"Type\":\"Photo\",\"AdminUserId\":0,\"DisplayText\":null,\"PostCreatedDate\":\"06/08/2018\",\"LikeCount\":4,\"CommentCount\":4,\"ViewCount\":3},{\"PostId\":3,\"UserId\":1,\"UserName\":\"party Patel\",\"ImagePath\":\"/Files/User/user_20180606_040913967_Hydrangeas.jpg\",\"FileId\":2110,\"FileName\":\"DiscovrUS.mov\",\"Email\":\"parth.patel@shaligraminfotech.com\",\"Location\":\"Ahmedabad\",\"PostDescription\":\"P7800\",\"PostPath\":\"/Files/NewsFeed/Video/ab48c228-d7b5-4dff-af56-31a0ac159a35.MOV\",\"UserRole\":\"Business\",\"BusinessName\":\"Shaligram infotech\",\"PostType\":true,\"Type\":\"Video\",\"AdminUserId\":0,\"DisplayText\":null,\"PostCreatedDate\":\"06/08/2018\",\"LikeCount\":1,\"CommentCount\":0,\"ViewCount\":1}]},{\"UserID\":2,\"post\":[{\"PostId\":2,\"UserId\":2,\"UserName\":\"tejas Padia\",\"ImagePath\":\"/Files/User/user_20180606_062946997_Tulips.jpg\",\"FileId\":2109,\"FileName\":\"DiscovrUS.mov\",\"Email\":\"tejaspadia@gmail.com\",\"Location\":\"India\",\"PostDescription\":\"P7800\",\"PostPath\":\"/Files/NewsFeed/Video/2d892eaf-b6dc-433d-985b-2a4588ffd307.MOV\",\"UserRole\":\"Individual\",\"BusinessName\":\"\",\"PostType\":true,\"Type\":\"Video\",\"AdminUserId\":0,\"DisplayText\":null,\"PostCreatedDate\":\"06/08/2018\",\"LikeCount\":3,\"CommentCount\":0,\"ViewCount\":0}]}]"
```

Comment: Use a `do/catch` with `try` so you can print the error.

Comment: may be you have invalid json format. Anyway put the code in `do/catch` as maddy said.

Comment: what is the value of `jsonData` ?

Comment: I have used do/catch but it goes to catch block that returns "failed".

Comment: @ParthPatel Did you print the error in that try catch? Error gives often tips/Reason on why. Don't just do `print("failed")`, print the error caught. Also, your `newsfeedData.rawString` is missing `{` at start and `}` at the end to be really valid (while the `.mutableContainers` might do some miracles, I saw it work for a single string value, but not like that).

Comment: I have printed string on Console and it is like:

Comment: Your `newsfeedData.rawString` is not a valid JSON. JSON cannot start with `Data:`. Remove the prefix `Data:` before converting the string to `Data`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure json format your value invalid format
just try replace `Data:` to empty string `""` , Your code it's working

```
  do{


        var  json = "Data:[{\"UserID\":1,\"post\":[{\"PostId\":1,\"UserId\":1,\"UserName\":\"party Patel\",\"ImagePath\":\"/Files/User/user_20180606_040913967_Hydrangeas.jpg\",\"FileId\":2108,\"FileName\":\"Business Category.png\",\"Email\":\"parth.patel@shaligraminfotech.com\",\"Location\":\"Ahmedabad\",\"PostDescription\":\"P7800\",\"PostPath\":\"/Files/NewsFeed/Photo/fd1c7fcf-e1d0-4ffe-afb4-42bb3fea4fa4.PNG\",\"UserRole\":\"Business\",\"BusinessName\":\"Shaligram infotech\",\"PostType\":false,\"Type\":\"Photo\",\"AdminUserId\":0,\"DisplayText\":null,\"PostCreatedDate\":\"06/08/2018\",\"LikeCount\":4,\"CommentCount\":4,\"ViewCount\":3},{\"PostId\":3,\"UserId\":1,\"UserName\":\"party Patel\",\"ImagePath\":\"/Files/User/user_20180606_040913967_Hydrangeas.jpg\",\"FileId\":2110,\"FileName\":\"DiscovrUS.mov\",\"Email\":\"parth.patel@shaligraminfotech.com\",\"Location\":\"Ahmedabad\",\"PostDescription\":\"P7800\",\"PostPath\":\"/Files/NewsFeed/Video/ab48c228-d7b5-4dff-af56-31a0ac159a35.MOV\",\"UserRole\":\"Business\",\"BusinessName\":\"Shaligram infotech\",\"PostType\":true,\"Type\":\"Video\",\"AdminUserId\":0,\"DisplayText\":null,\"PostCreatedDate\":\"06/08/2018\",\"LikeCount\":1,\"CommentCount\":0,\"ViewCount\":1}]},{\"UserID\":2,\"post\":[{\"PostId\":2,\"UserId\":2,\"UserName\":\"tejas Padia\",\"ImagePath\":\"/Files/User/user_20180606_062946997_Tulips.jpg\",\"FileId\":2109,\"FileName\":\"DiscovrUS.mov\",\"Email\":\"tejaspadia@gmail.com\",\"Location\":\"India\",\"PostDescription\":\"P7800\",\"PostPath\":\"/Files/NewsFeed/Video/2d892eaf-b6dc-433d-985b-2a4588ffd307.MOV\",\"UserRole\":\"Individual\",\"BusinessName\":\"\",\"PostType\":true,\"Type\":\"Video\",\"AdminUserId\":0,\"DisplayText\":null,\"PostCreatedDate\":\"06/08/2018\",\"LikeCount\":3,\"CommentCount\":0,\"ViewCount\":0}]}]"

        json = json.replacingOccurrences(of: "Data:", with: "")
        if let data = json.data(using: .utf8) {
            do {
                let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String: Any]]
                print(jsonResult)
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you @a.masri. It worked for me. You saved my day.

Comment: @ParthPatel Good lock , but this is not a perfect solution , you need check json format

Comment: Yes sure, I will check it.

Comment: Adding `{` and `}` at start/end might be a better solution in case there is `Data:` somewhere in the rest of the JSON stringified.